# How do you use .filter() on a table?

Tags: javascript, filter

I am having troubles using .filter() on my table. It consists of 5 cells, I need to filter the table based on the content/value of the last cell (index 4). It has 3 possible values: 'Node.JS', 'ReactJS', and 'AngularJS'. If the user wants the table to be filtered for 'Node.JS', I want all the table data to be deleted (the html only, I have everything saved to localStorage) and all the rows containing 'Node.JS' be added to a new object (filteredData). Then I wish to call my createTable function on the new object, but I can't seem to filter it properly. Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated (please no JQuery) :)

```
function filterTable() {
        const filterBy = document.getElementById('filter'); // filter option select
        const rows = table.rows;
        const savedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        let filteredData = savedData.filter(function () {
            for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { // i = 1 to skip header
                if (filterBy.value === 'Node.JS' && rows[i].cells[4].innerText === 'Node.JS') {
                    filteredData = savedData.filter(rows[i].cells[4].innerText); // I tried using return, but that only stops the function
                } else if (filterBy.value === 'ReactJS' && rows[i].cells[4].innerText === 'ReactJS') {
                    filteredData = savedData.filter(rows[i].cells[4].innerText);
                } else if (filterBy.value === 'AngularJS' && rows[i].cells[4].innerText === 'AngularJS') {
                    filteredData = savedData.filter(rows[i].cells[4].innerText);
                }
                console.log(filteredData);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the purpose is to create a list of the data that matches something in `savedData` then just filter `savedData` and ignore anything in the table.

Comment: Can you post an example of the data stored in local storage i.e savedData ?

Comment: Here's an example: {name: "bilbo", nachname: "baggins", bday: "20.05.2021", beruf: "Hobbit", veranstaltung: "Node.JS"}

Comment: @DaveNewton How would the code look? What you're saying makes sense, but Idk how to apply it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, this is the way I made it work for myself. I'll leave the question up incase anyone can make use of it. Thanks everyone for the help <3

```
function filterTable() {
        const filterBy = document.getElementById('filter'); // filter option select
        const savedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        let filteredArray;
        if (filterBy.value === 'Node.JS') {
            filteredArray = savedData.filter(function (e) {
                return e.veranstaltung === 'Node.JS';
            })
        } else if (filterBy.value === 'ReactJS') {
            filteredArray = savedData.filter(function (e) {
                return e.veranstaltung === 'ReactJS';
            })
        } else if (filterBy.value === 'AngularJS') {
            filteredArray = savedData.filter(function (e) {
                return e.veranstaltung === 'AngularJS';
            })
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < filteredArray.length; i++) {
            createTable(filteredArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Filter in a wrong way.

Here is an example on how to use `filter()`

```js
var array = [{name:"Alen"}, {name:"Toma"}]
var filterValue = "al"

var result = array.filter(function(x){ return x.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLowerCase()) != -1})


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Now, Why would I have to? The data of the storage in this example is an array so it will be the same as my variable array

Comment: {name: "bilbo", nachname: "baggins", bday: "20.05.2021", beruf: "Hobbit", veranstaltung: "Node.JS"}

Comment: This is not an array but an object so you may check if you can use `Object.values` or `Object.names` then use `filter()`

Comment: SavedData is actually an array of objects. It actually looks like this: [{name: "bilbo", nachname: "baggins", bday: "20.05.2021", beruf: "Hobbit", veranstaltung: "Node.JS"}]

Comment: So you can then use my example do it easly then